# Trying to implement multiple conditional operator

Tags: c#

I'm trying to implement multiple conditional operator but issue is that always if condition is true.

My requirement is

if `Headername[CI]== "Yellow"`.

And `objnamewritten[CI]== "Banana" or objnamewritten[CI] == "Sun" or objnamewritten[CI] == "lemomn"`.

Then popup(`ppup`) will open, if there is any other `objnamewritten[CI]` then popup(`ppup1`) will open.

```
private void common()
{
    if (Headername[CI]== "Yellow")
    {
        if ((objnamewritten[CI]== "Banana" | objnamewritten[CI] == "Sun")|(objnamewritten[CI] == "lemomn" | objnamewritten[CI] == "Sun"))
        {
            ppup.Height = Window.Current.Bounds.Height;
            ppup.IsOpen = true;
        }
        else
        {
            ppup1.Height = Window.Current.Bounds.Height;
            ppup1.IsOpen = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "or" should be `||` instead of `|`

Comment: @fubo I tried using || instead | but it won't work

Comment: What does "it won't work" entail? errors? invalid results?

Comment: Use `String.Compare` when comparing strings so the correct culture and case sensitivity can be taken into account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two things which you are missing in your code.

1. You are not using OR operator correctly
2. You should use Equals method to compare strings (A good practice)

Following code should work:

```
    private void common()
    {
         if (Headername[CI] == "Yellow")
         {
                 if (objnamewritten[CI].Equals("Banana") || objnamewritten[CI].Equals("lemomn") || objnamewritten[CI].Equals("Sun"))
                {
                     ppup.Height = Window.Current.Bounds.Height;
                     ppup.IsOpen = true;
                }
                else
                {
                   ppup1.Height = Window.Current.Bounds.Height;
                   ppup1.IsOpen = true;
                }              
          }
          else
          {
                   ppup1.Height = Window.Current.Bounds.Height;
                   ppup1.IsOpen = true;
          }
   }
```

Comment: This code will not work like the opp intended ! if HeaderName[CI] is somethig different from Yellow he wants to open ppup1. At least he wrote this.

Comment: Why do you have to use Equals to compare strings? OP's question is about C#, where the `==` operator has been overloaded for strings.

Comment: "if there is any other objnamewritten[CI] then popup(ppup1) will open." He does not mentioned any else case for Headername[CI] not equal to "Yellow"

Comment: @M.SherazLeo I tried your code but it always opening ppup not ppup1.

Comment: If Headername[CI] is not "Yellow" then what you want to do? open popup1?

Comment: @M.SherazLeo I Headername[CI] is not "Yellow" then are other colors and for those colors different objnamewritten[CI] is there .I tried your updated code also but always it is opening "ppup" Popup.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a select:

```
private void common()
{
   if (Headername[CI]== "Yellow")
    {
     switch (objnamewritten[CI])
      {
        case "Banana":
        case "Sun":
        case "lemomn":
            ppup.Height = Window.Current.Bounds.Height;
            ppup.IsOpen = true;
            break;
        default:
            ppup1.Height = Window.Current.Bounds.Height;
            ppup1.IsOpen = true;
            break;
       }
    }
}
```